# Android, Splash screen shows next activity

Tags: android, android-activity, splash-screen

I've created Splash -> `SplashActivity.java`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    pref = new Prefs(getApplicationContext());
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this,
                        MainActivity.class));
                SplashActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }, 1000);
}
```

and here is a problem , when I quit the app by pressing `Home_Button` and then run the app again, Splash come again (that I down't want see it again).

even I checked `onPause` and `onStop` events but it dowsn't work.

**Edit**

my splash is transparent and the problem is showing `MainActivity` at behind, not starting from splash (because of memory).

Comment: I don't think you can control it. It's all upto Android. Maybe because of low memory it is killing your app and when you start, it is starting from Splash screen.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to store a flag, that would indicate that your splash has already been shown. Check it in `onCreate()` method of your splash screen and if it is present, launch the next activity.

Some code for reference:

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs;
final String splashDisplayedSharePref = "splashScreenShown";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

// second argument is the default to use if the preference can't be found
Boolean splashDisplayed = mPrefs.getBoolean(splashDisplayedSharePref, false);

if (!splashDisplayed) {
    // here you can launch another activity if you like
    // the code below will display a popup

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(splashDisplayedSharePref, true);
    editor.commit(); // Very important to save the preference
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this,
                    MainActivity.class));
            SplashActivity.this.finish();
        }
    }, 1000);

}
else
{
// Splash displayed. Directly start the next activity.
startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this,
                    MainActivity.class));
}

}
```

Comment: May be you are misunderstand the question.your answer is valid if the op wants the splash only once at the time starting installation..but here the problem is after relaunch of the app from background splash screen is coming..

Comment: @kalyanpvs. When the person logs out, the boolean value can be set to false, so that each time when the user logs in after a successful logout, the user will be able to view the splash screen.

Comment: yes in your way by changing the boolean value to false on logout we can achieve.but here is no logout functionality ..here user needs set to false when the MainActivity (which is top Activity)  onDestroy() method..

Comment: there is a very big problem, I want my splash as the first activity to run, because when you run `MainActivity` and then `finish()` it to run the `SplashActivity` , it will face the `transactionAnimation` that is activated automatically in many devices. I mean the user will understand the change.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a possibility that your phone is having low memory, so when pressing home button the app goes into the background & the memory allocated to it may be deallocated(i.e process is killed), when you relaunch the app(from long press of home button, or by any other method), it is launched from the start & memory is again allocated.

And If you want that you should see splash only the first time you launch your app in phone then use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).